# Windows Forms: choose from list without creating a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm writing a console application which actually sometimes has to use GUI elements.

In particular, choosing one string from a list of strings is needed to be performed through GUI. It has to be something like:

```
public static string SelectString(List<string> strings)
{
    string selectedString;

    // GUI part

    return selectedString;
}
```

Is it possible to make it in a way like using `FolderBrowserDialog`? For example, I'm using the following code to choose a folder:

```
public static string SelectFolder(string description)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        folderBrowserDialog.Description = description;

        return folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
            ? folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
            : null;
    }
}
```

I'm aware of `ListBox` but it requires creating a form.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can create the form dynamically at run-time.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I see, but then I have to set dimensions, position and all the other stuff. I'd like to use something lightweight like `FolderBrowserDialog` or `OpenFileDialog`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DfM You're correct, you'll need to set some items.  I don't think there's a built in item that does what you want.  If it's a really simple form it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Why not just add a form to your console app (not a problem to do) and just call the form?  That way you don't have to hard code all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the form directly in your code.  Here's a very simple example.  You'd probably want to add an `OK` Button.

```
Form frm = new Form();
ListBox listbox1 = new ListBox();
frm.Controls.Add(listbox1);
listbox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.ShowDialog();

int selectedIndex = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
```

To avoid hard coding you could add a `Form` to your console app and just call up the form:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

In this case you may want to set the `Modifier` property of your `ListBox` to `public` so that you can access it after the dialog closes.